# Отрисовка swf в C#

Tags: c#, swf, graphics

Есть изображения в формате swf (пример: http://mapviewer.ru/img/tramvay/depo_d.swf)
Необходимо это изображение нарисовать на картинке (Bitmap -> Graphics)

Какие библиотеки для этого использовать, может быть надо как-то конвертировать swf в картинку? Все это надо делать на лету, без лишних кликов на конвертацию и прочее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено, содержимое swf распапсил с помощью [SwfDotNet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16834/How-to-create-a-simple-SWF-decompiler-with-the-Swf), а затем вектор отрисовал на Bitmap